# The probability of a randomly generated floating point number is in a certain range

Tags: floating-point, probability

Let's say I randomly generate a number and check if it is in a certain range. 
For integer, it's simple. For example with unsigned 8 bits, the randomly generated number can be in range (0 - 5 inclusive) with the probability of (6/2^8).

My question is how can I calculate the same thing with floating point number. For example, when I just randomly generate 32bits, what is the probability that the number is within a range of -10.0 and 10.0?

Comment: What's wrong with `(a - b)/(MAX - MIN)` (where `a` and `b` are the end points of your interval, and `MAX` and `MIN` are the max/min number that could be generated)?

Comment: @arshajii: Because it's floating point number, the density of numbers distributed is not uniform.

Comment: This might help - [Conversion of High-Period Random Numbers to
Floating Point](http://www.doornik.com/research/randomdouble.pdf).

Comment: To add to the fun, some patterns of 32 bits are not IEEE 754 numbers -- they are non-numeric values; either +inf or -inf or NaN. There are lots of NaN patterns.

Comment: As a first approximation, the numbers will be logarithmically distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a binary representation, the probability can be computed for ranges [2^n,2^n+1)
For example, if exponent is on 11 bits, probability is 1/2^12 (taking sign into account)

Inside such interval, it's possible to consider a uniform density of floating point.

Then I guess you could try and decompose your interval into such powers of 2 boundaries.
Then compute the probability of each interval, and sum them all...
Assuming there is a IEEE-754-like denormal representation, for the smallest possible exponent e, interval is [0,2^e[
So this should give you a rather simple procedure, but I see no simple formula.

For very accurate probabilities, you'll have to deal with the significand bit pattern of nearest representable float inside the interval for lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to make progress by looking at the IEEE 754 representation of 10.0 (EDIT: or whatever value is of interest) -- a float which is less in magnitude than that has a smaller exponent, or the same exponent and a mantissa which is smaller. I'm guessing that you can figure out how many possible values there are for the exponent and mantissa and go from there.